# BS4 returns HTML missing elements

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape Momondo. I'm interested in the price that can be found here

```
<div class="price-price">182 USD</div>
```

I'm scraping with the following code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request

url = 'https://www.momondo.com/flight-search/PAR-BER/2018-07-22?sort=price_a'
response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
html = response.read()
print(html)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html5lib')
all = soup.find_all('div',class_='price-price')
for item in all:
    print(item.text)
```

Response and hence html do not contain a class 'price-price'. Can you point me to my error?

Comment: I cannot see an element with class "price-price" - whereabouts on the page is this? Also, the page appears to check regularly that scraping is not occuring which might indicate it is against the T&C's of the site.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the element you're trying to capture is dynamically generated by JavaScript. `request` gets the content before this even happens.

For situations like these there are 2 things you can do,

1. Recommended way of doing it is to use something else, like [selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/index.html) to get the page source.
2. Check the network tab in browser's developer tools and see if the data file is getting downloaded, this is a hack-y kinda way and will not always work.